# QEMU with KVM: guest to use a OpenVPN connection that doesn't exist on host

Tags: linux, networking, openvpn, qemu

Most posts that touch on this subject wants to use the host's VPN. In my case, I want the guest VM to have its own OpenVPN connection that exists **only** on the guest VM. The host will have a normal, non-encrypted connection.

What is the correct way to accomplish this using QEMU?

Answer (score 0):

Set up your VM as per normal and run OpenVPN inside it.  You need to make sure that it can communicate with OpenVPN server on port 1194 or whatever you configure.

This should typically *just work* provided there are no firewalls preventing it.

Comment: Would this work with a normal pass-through setup? Networking has never been my strong suit. The recommened settings on the Gentoo wiki are the following: `-device virtio-net,netdev=vmnic -netdev user,id=vmnic`. Does this mean it will have its own IP address on the local network? None of the of the other options mentioned [here](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/QEMU/Options#Networking) makes much sense to me.

Thank you.

Comment: I can't answer the specifics as per your comment above, but provided the VM has an IP address which can see the OpenVPN server this should just work - it really does not matter what kind of networking the VM has, as OpenVPN is compatible with NAT.  The options above look to be fully virtualised, so the network interface IP address will not be the same as the host.